# How to prove that a matrix $U$ is unitary, if and only if the columns form an orthonormal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

And also, is it true that a matrix is unitary if and only if $T^{-1}=T^{*}$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are solving a question of the form "$x$ is a *gadget* if and only if $x$ satisfies $p$", you know immediately that gadgets can be given multiple (at least 2!) equivalent definitions. So, it becomes important to state which definition you are using in order to usefully discuss the problem with people.

Comment: In this case, there are many possible definitions. For example, if $U$ is an $n \times n$ complex matrix, then the following are equivalent: (1) $U^*U = I$ (2) $U^{-1} = U^*$ (3) $(Ux) \cdot (Uy) = x \cdot y$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n$ (4) the columns of $U$ are an orthonormal set (5) $Ux$ and $x$ have the same length for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ etc etc etc. Any one of these could reasonably be taken as the definition of a unitary matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition a matrix $T$ is unitary if $T^*T=I.$

For two real matrices $A,B$, the $i,j$ entry of $AB$ is the inner product of the $i$ row of $A$ and $j$ column of $B$. Therefore the $i,j$ entry of $T^*T$ is the inner product of the $i$ row of $T^t$ and $j$ column of $T$ which is the $i$ column of $T$ and the $j$ column of $T$. Now use that $T$ is unitary if and only if the $i,j$ entry of $T^*T$ is $\delta_{i,j}=\begin{cases}0, \ \text{ if } i\neq j \\ 1, \ \text{ if } i= j \end{cases}.$

Answer (score 3):

A square matrix is unitary when $T^*T=I.$

Hint 1: Suppose $T$ is a square matrix. Write it in block form as a bunch of column vectors. What is the $(1,1)$ entry of $T^*T$? What is the $(i,j)$ entry? What can you conclude?

Hint 2: If $T^*T=I$, can $T$ be singular? Can you think of any operation you might do to this equation to get $T^*=T^{-1}$?